# Render component with ajax in jsf

Tags: jsf-2

The problem is, when I set the render attribute of f:ajax  to @form the btnCreateCSV render correctly. But, if I change it to the id of button nothing happen. I wonder to know, how can I solve this problem.
This is my xhtml code :

```
<h:panelGrid layout="block">
            <h:commandButton value="View SQL" action="#{sparqlQueryBean.convert}" id="btnViewSql">
                <f:ajax execute="txtQuery btnCreateCSV" render="btnCreateCSV txtSqlQuery" onevent="waiting" listener="#{sparqlQueryBean.generateCommands}"></f:ajax>
            </h:commandButton>
            <h:commandButton value = "CSV" action = "#{sparqlQueryBean.createCSV}" id = "btnCreateCSV" rendered="#{sparqlQueryBean.showCSV == true}">
                <f:ajax execute="@none" render = "@none" onevent="waiting"></f:ajax>
            </h:commandButton>
```

And it's my bean class. In generateCommands method, the value of showCSV set to true. But it dosn't work.

```
    public void generateCommands (AjaxBehaviorEvent event) {
    this.setShowCSV(true);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `<f:ajax>`, JavaScript is used to locate elements in the HTML DOM tree and re-render them. But if a JSF component is not rendered into the HTML output, then there's also nothing in the HTML DOM tree to re-render. You should either re-render its closest parent component which is always rendered instead, or wrap it in another component (e.g. `<h:panelGroup>`) which is always rendered and re-render it instead.

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2 - Ajax rendering of content which is by itself conditionally rendered](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#AjaxRenderingOfContentWhichIsByItselfConditionallyRendered)